# Set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE through uwsgi

Tags: django, uwsgi

I am trying to find the best way to split my django settings, and have the different settings files served for dev and prod.

My wsgi file:

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

and in my uwsgi.ini file I have this:

```
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project.settings.local
wsgi-file = project/wsgi.py
```

But the env from the uwsgi.ini file is not passed to wsgi. If I print os.environ in the wsgi file the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is not set.

Any ideas?

Comment: why dont you set it in `wsgi.py` ?

Comment: because then I would need different wsgi files for dev and production and staging

Comment: The syntax looks correct so there is not enough information to guess what could be wrong. Try isolate all config files to a repeatable test case.

Answer (score 5):

I like doing something like this in wsgi.py:

```
import os
import socket

socket_name = socket.gethostname()
if "stage" in socket_name:
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproject.settings.staging')
elif "prod" in socket_name:
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproject.settings.production')
else:
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproject.settings.local')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Your method of detecting whether you're on staging, prod, or local can be whatever you'd like, but the os.environ.setdefault command seems like it'll accomplish what you're hoping to do.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to also set the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE in the bin/activate file. I have added it after export PATH like so:

```
export PATH
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE='project.settings.local'
```

You should find your bin folder in your project environment folder.